# CouchDB sys.config file location

Tags: erlang, couchdb

I'm trying to set up a CouchDB cluster as per the instructions on their Github page. Part of the process involves changing a few `sys.config` values as mentioned here: https://github.com/apache/couchdb-documentation/blob/master/src/cluster/setup.rst#make-couchdb-use-the-open-ports

Can someone point me to the location of this file for my CouchDB installation? I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on my machine.

Comment: Which version of CouchDB, and how did you install it?

Answer (score 0):

You can find this file by executing:

`find . -name sys.config`

in the top level of your couchdb installation.

For example:

```
find . -name sys.config
./releases/2.0.0/sys.config
```